# Report Detail Band Not Populating

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I am new to PB and retrieving my report.  My header and footer populate
but not my detail band. My arguments seem to be working correctly.  Any ideas:

Comment: Maybe that you could give more details... Does the request that the DW is based upon returns the correct result if you try it with iSQL ( or  PSQL or whatever - replace with your DBMS shell tool) ? If you query `RowCount()` on the DW is it > 0 ? Did you set a height of 0 to the `Detail` band ? ...

Comment: When you say "header and footer populate", are you saying "populated with data from the data set", or "populated with functions like Page() and Date()"? FYI, the bands all feed off of one data set, so the former would be unusual. The latter might indicate you haven't gotten any rows of data back.

Comment: Magic 8-Ball says: Call SetTrans or SetTransObject before retrieving the DataWindow.

Answer (score -1):

I know the thread is old but I thought I could share my solution all the same :

I am using collection from Java Beans.

```
// Using compiled version(.jasper) of Jasper report to generate PDF
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(inStream, parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(mainCollection,false));
```

If you pass an empty main data collection, then detail bands are never rendered, even if you have only static data on them.

This is because details are used to rendered this main data collection. If you don't pass any main data, then no point in rendering them at all.

See this thread for more info : [Detail Band Not Shown When Dataset NOT Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37600489/detail-band-not-shown-when-dataset-not-empty)

Looks like there is an option to bypass this limitation.

Comment: Although the term _detail band_ is used by other _report_  generators like Java-based [tag:Jasper-Reports], this question is on the Windows-tool, see the question tagged [tag:Powerbuilder]. So your answer is off-topic. You could search a matching question and post it there ️

Comment: Thank you for this remark. It's funny how much sense this question made at this time, I didn't even realize it was on another software... apologies for that